# Can UIStackview with 2 UILabels dynamically adjust based on contents?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uistackview

I have an image view and 2 labels as shown below
[image]

both the labels need to dynamically adjust based on the text set.

I tried to add UIImageView and 2 UILabels in UIStackView
but Labels are not showing up correctly

any suggestions on how I can achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean font scaling?

Comment: if so, set a stack height constraint

Comment: No, Fonts are fixed. Dont want to fix stackview height, want it to grow dynamically

Comment: i don't understand the question, how do you want the labels to show up differently?

Comment: i just want as in image attached, without setting any width constraints to both the Labels

Comment: check stack view distribution property

Comment: @Keshav - you cannot have 2 multiline labels without giving one of them a width (it can be explicit or calculated or percentage, etc). Is `Right side Text` label only a single line label?

Comment: Yes, it's possible!!
It's may be due to imageview, try without imageview

Comment: @DonMag, yes right side label is single line and middle one should support multi line

Comment: @SPatel I want to have imageview as well

Comment: Did you try it or not?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily by setting Content Hugging and Content Compression Resistance on the "Right side Label":

[image]

Here is how it looks in Storyboard. I gave the elements background colors to make it easy to see the frames:

[image]

The stack view properties are:

[image]

Here's how it looks with different text in the right side label:

[image]

[image]

and, clearing the background colors:

[image]

[image]